# A study in JOINs with many-to-many relationships

Tags: sql, t-sql, database-design

Consider, if you will, the following tables:

[Vacation Model http://imagetiger.org/images/vacatilrl.png](http://imagetiger.org/images/vacatilrl.png)

This may seem like a strange structure, but allow me to explain.  The goal of this structure is to create a report listing all people, excluding those on vacation (for simplicity, we'll pretend that the vacation record will only exist if a person is on vacation.)

The reason I have the Vacation table at all is because the Event table is a more general use table for "insignificant" events, whereas the Vacation table includes more details such as the location and date.

What I can't seem to figure out is how to design a query that includes, say, Person.personId and Vacation.location, but only those personIds that exist in Person_Vacation.  Or the inverse, only personIds that DO NOT exist in Person_Vacation.

Also, does this seem to be the best way to implement this solution, design-wise?  Any ideas on what I might have done wrong or suggested improvements?

**EDIT:**  Maybe i'm just not too good at communicating my intentions:  turns out getting only the persons on vacation is easy, but i would like to perform the inverse, basically all persons NOT on vacation.

Comment: It seems like two quite simple queries... what exactly is the problem? What have you tried so far and why is it failing? The first one seems to just be a simple JOIN... have you tried that? The second one is not quite so obvious but is a very common question - records that exist in one table but not in another. Do you know about NOT EXISTS?

Comment: Please say exactly what you want your queries to produce -- as it stands, your requirements could be interpreted in a way that means no outer joins are needed at all.  E.g. `SELECT * FROM Person JOIN Person_Event USING (personId) JOIN Vacation USING (eventId)` shows you all and only those people on vacation (multiple times if they're on multiple vacations).

Comment: @j_random_hacker: Yeah good point. @Mark Byers: Do not make a title instigating some solution if you are not sure its on the right track.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Design-wise I don't see why you need `Person_Vacation`. If I understand your design correctly, every vacation is an event (i.e. "inheritance"), so the connection between `Vacation` and `Person` can be made through `Person_Event`. Then the queries would be:

Persons in vacation:

```
SELECT P.PersonID, V.locaton
FROM Person P, Vacation V, Person_Event PE
WHERE P.personid = PE.personID AND PE.eventid = V.eventid
```

Persons in NON-vacation events:

```
SELECT P.PersonID, E.title
FROM Person P, Person_Event PE, Event E
WHERE P.personid = PE.personID AND PE.eventid = E.eventid
AND E.eventID NOT IN (SELECT eventid FROM Vacation)
```

Persons not on *any* vacation:

```
SELECT P.PersonID, E.title
FROM Person P, Person_Event PE, Event E
WHERE P.personid = PE.personID AND PE.eventid = E.eventid
AND P.personID NOT IN 
  (SELECT personid FROM Person_Event PE, Vacation V WHERE PE.eventid = V.eventid)
```

If you want to go with your own design, then you have to decide if you will insert a person's vacation only in `Person_Vacation` or in `Person_Vacation` and `Person_Event`. If you do the former, then the queries above would become a bit simpler.

However I would still vote for my design, because what you are essentially doing is prematurely splitting data just to get a bit of performance / simplicity. This may not pay off in the long run.

Comment: Good point.  Though that model does make the query I'm looking for only require 3 tables (Person to Vacation through Person_Vacation) instead of 4 (Person to Event through Person_Event, to Vacation through Event).

Comment: Depends on which query you meen, see queries above. If you wanna continue along the lines of your own desing you do *not* need any NOT EXISTS / NOT IN predicates at all, as Person_Vacation should only include person-vacation links and Person_Event only non-vacation links. Though I don't like such design too much.

Comment: @wtfsven: You only need 4 tables in the query if there are some fields in Event (e.g. title) that you need.  Otherwise, you don't need the Event table at all in the query -- you can link directly from Person_Event to Vacation. But even if you do need fields from Event, a 4-table join is not something to worry about.

Comment: I agree that Person_Vacation is redundant and not required.

Answer (score 0):

Probably I didn't full understand in your database design. If `Vocation` is also an event and the `Person_Event` table has all events which conserned the person `personId` then the table should contain the subset of `Person_Vacation` and one can eliminate it. Moreover all persons have sometime vocation so I would find more logical to include a dates in some tables.

Nevetheless how I understend your database design you can receive the results which you want with a query like following

```
SELECT p.name, e.title
FROM Person AS p
    INNER JOIN Person_Event AS pe ON p.personId = pe.personId
    INNER JOIN [Event] AS e ON pe.eventId = e.eventId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Vacation AS v ON e.eventId = v.eventId
WHERE v.eventId IS NULL
```

Comment: Conceptually this should work, but the flaw here is that there is not necessarily a row in Vacation for every row in Event, so the WHERE v.eventId IS NULL causes it to return nothing, and removing the WHERE clause returns those on vacation.